# TokenMismatchException when uploading a Video?

Tags: php, laravel-5

When uploading a image, laravel goes through everything fine and dandy. No dramas.
as soon as I upload a video file, nope. Pops up with:.

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:

I have a valdiator:

```
$fileVali = \Validator::make(

    ['file' => \Input::file('media')],
    ['file' => 'required|image']

            );
```

here is the blade form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'post', 'url' => '/post', 'class' => 'uk-form uk-width-1-1', 'files' => true)) !!}
{!! Form::text('post', NULL , array('class' => 'uk-form-blank uk-form-large', 'placeholder' => 'Whats Up ' . Session::get('user') . '?')) !!}
{!! Form::file('media' , '', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Update:**
I have found that the issue is popping up because I'm uploading quite a large video file (65mb). Laravel had a issue with file size before but didn't pop back with validation errors!!anyone know what is going on?

**Update 2: The Return Of The Update**

Ok, so my route:

```
Route::post('/post', 'FeedController@create');
```

Comment: does your form have a hidden csfr_token field something like this <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

Comment: Yes, I use blade, so the hidden token is automatically generated (I also checked and it is being generated.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to your **update**, you said, `"Laravel had a issue with file size"`.

If that the case, I don't think is Laravel. It's your PHP configuration.

Have you update these directives in your **php.ini** file to fit your need.

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Comment: Yes I have! I have updated. But Like i said, if it was file size, laravel would of spitted the PHP error like it has done when I have uploaded larger files.

Comment: Can we see how do you declare your routes ? Update that on your post, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: This was the fix. I did change the values, but in the wrong php.ini (I use Mamp in windows, and to be able to run laravel, I had to install php 5.5.19) I laterforgot that the php.ini file was located somehwere else -.-

Comment: After restarting my computer because all else failed...it worked. I forgot that to use laravel I installed raw PHP on windows, and just ran artisan serv. Because I also used to use MAMP, I was updating the wrong php.ini
Sorry for wasting your guys time -.- But thanks for the response! This was the fix in the end!!!

Comment: I'm very glad I could help.

Comment: This solution helped me a lot. thank you so much.  I really appreciate it.