# TokenMismatchException Issue on File Upload

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.3

I've been finagling with this for a couple hours. I've read all the posts on the GitHub issue twice, and most everything seems to be working. I can login/logout/register fine. The only issue I'm having is submitting a form with "enctype" set to "multipart/form-data" (for files). I'm inclined to believe that the HTML encoding is somehow messing up the "_token" value, but I'm not sure. I tried to dd the request before the CSRF middleware kicked in. Nothing seems amiss. Any help would be appreciated.

Controller Code

```
public function uploadPodcast(Request $request) 
{
    $request->file('podcast')->store('podcasts', 's3');
    redirect()->back();
}
```

Blade Template Code

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/podcast-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <label>Podcast File</label>
    <input type="file" name="podcast" id="podcast">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Error

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Are you passing `csrf_token` with the form submission?

Comment: Added code. Yes I am.

Comment: Added error (such as it is)

Comment: Could you try uploading a file of a small size say 1 mb.. also check the read write permissions of that folder..

Comment: Well isn't that something. I got a different error but that's an issue with resolving connection to S3. Would never of guessed the file size being the issue.

Comment: Could  be an issue with `upload_max_filesize /post_max_size `.

Comment: Yeah I have been through it lol hence guessed

Comment: Mind if i post it as an answer?

Comment: Go ahead! Thanks for the guidance. :)

Comment: Thanks :) and good luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TokenMismatchException when uploading a Video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047977/tokenmismatchexception-when-uploading-a-video)

Answer (score 0):

give Recursive permission to the storage folder of your project **sudo chmod -R 777 storage/**